# How to set up a callable for Django Imagefield's >> default << parameter

Tags: python, django

So I have a Model that will contain a couple hundred instances and I now added an imagefield `logo`. As I don't want to upload each and every logo via the admin manually, I want to set up a callable that returns the correct file path so I can just push the logos to `media/company_logos`. Due to some technical hick-up I can push the logos to the folder only after creating their instance.

```
# models.py

def logo_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return f'company_logos/{instance.symbol}'

class Company(models.Model):

    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_logos/', default=logo_directory_path(instance=symbol, filename=f'{symbol}.png'))
```

This returns an error at `instance=symbol` saying

> Type 'str' doesn't have expected attribute 'symbol'

Another approach was

```
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_logos/', default=f'company_logos/{symbol}')
```

which returns a URL as `src="/media/company_logos/<django.db.models.fields.CharField>"`

I am not quiet sure how to set this up as I cant fully understand the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

My desired outcome is to have a URL for `default` like so:

`company_logos/IBM.png` with field `symbol` being the corresponding part (I tried it via f-string).

Update to Ankits request --> When trying to create a new instance with the code suggested it throws

> logo_directory_path() missing 2 required positional arguments:
> 'instance' and 'filename'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the logic in the [**`uploaded_to=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), so:

```
from pathlib import Path


class Company(models.Model):
    def logo_directory_path(self, filename):
        return f'company_logos/{self.symbol}{Path(filename).suffix}'

    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=logo_directory_path)
```